# React Native best practices for API handling

Tags: networking, react-native, fetch

I've been working on the React Native platform this last couple of months and I need to implement a solid way to handle my API calls. At the moment I'm using redux to manage satate changes. Obviously the requestes must have a couple of retries if there is no network available, refresh oAuth tokens, etc.

Three solutions have ocurred to me:

1. **Implement a "manager" class and handle all the logic in there.** I like this one but I don't know if is possible to connect a non-component to redux since they dont have state.
2. Implement a couple of redux actions(request, onResponse, onError...)  which should do the trick.
3. **Create separated redux actions** with their own fetchs to every call instead of having a centralized component.

What solution should I implement?

Another problem I've faced is that if a Network Error happens the promise is resolved even if I call the request again and I'm no longer able to make the behavior programmed in the caller method. Any workarounds?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux has two powerful libraries that are designed to work with async API calls. These allow you to handle retries, errors, and slow API calls in the background of your app, simply by listening for a specific action.

Redux-thunk or Redux-saga are what you are probably going to want to use, so that you do not have to do all of the work of managing how components deal with API calls.  Strongly recommend you check these out - there are quite a few tutorials out there that describe how to use these modules. Doing this by hand is not a good best practice IMO.

Comment: and how would you listen for a specific action outside a reducer?

Comment: I am guessing here why you would want to do this, but you may want to look at redux-saga first, which handles side-effects as actions which you can listen for and trigger separately.  Have a look at this question if this is the case:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949597/listening-for-a-redux-action.  Would help to know what your use case actually is.

Answer (score 2):

For api handling. you can have one single file which will have all function (export) and other settings needed so that you just have to import required methods.

You can use starter kit for react-native for basic structure for example: https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit

it provides most of the things that we need for fresh project setup.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the pattern mentioned in the below tutorial(youtube link below)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mlwjZL3Fmw

Everyone uses this pattern for API calls when following redux in react-native.

The tutorial is really good,its a great video.

Comment: actually this is a really simple call. I'm trying to manage at least +50 different API calls, so it came to my mind that maybe is more efficiente to create a "manager" instead of a fetch in every action I dispatch.